# PAUSED SQL Server still uses 20% CPU

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server is always using 15% to 40% or more on a very lightly used database (maybe 40 users log in ONCE a day for literally a min or two). A small load procedure runs for maybe 15 min daily.

- Anytime day or night the SQL Server is always using CPU. NO processes are running (who is active shows no one at all)
- Even when the database is paused, still using 15%+ CPU
- SQL Server 15 Express, Windows 2016 server, Azure VM

Any ideas? Thanks in advance,

Rich

Comment: Are you sure it's lightly used?  Have you run SQL Server Profiler to see what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

FYI - Issue resolved.  Turns out just not enough memory on system.  Whenever memory got too low, sql server went bonkers.  Increased memory and problem went away.